# White line between status bar and WebView on iPhone 14 Pro/Pro Max

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, webview

I put a WebView inside my app, as you can see from the image everything works fine on iPhones with the notch (I tried on both iOS 15 and 16), while on the new 14 Pro and Pro Max there is a white line that appears between the end of the status bar and the beginning of the WebView. I thought it might be a bug in the Simulator, but i'm not so sure... Is there some way to hide that line without messing with the other devices?

Here is the code I'm using for the WebView and for the specific tab:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

struct SearchView: View {
    
    let sysLanguage = NSLocale.current.languageCode
    
    var body: some View {
        if sysLanguage == "it" {
            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.vivibusso.app/webapp_test/it/search.html")!)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
        } else {
            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.vivibusso.app/webapp_test/it/search.html")!)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct SearchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SearchView()
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selected = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            NavigationView {
                HomeView()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (selected == 0 ? "house.fill" : "house"))
                Text("Home")
            }.tag(0)
            NavigationView {
                CategoryView()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (selected == 1 ? "text.justify" : "text.justify"))
                Text("Categorie")
            }.tag(1)
            NavigationView {
                GalleryView()
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (selected == 2 ? "photo.fill" : "photo"))
                Text("Galleria")
            }.tag(2)
            NavigationView {
                SearchView()
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (selected == 3 ? "magnifyingglass" : "magnifyingglass"))
                Text("Ricerca")
            }.tag(3)
        }
        .accentColor(.white)
        .onAppear() {
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 125.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 159.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 125.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 159.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let app = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        let statusBarHeight = app?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        let statusbarView = UIView()
        statusbarView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 125.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 159.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        view.addSubview(statusbarView)
        statusbarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        statusbarView.heightAnchor
            .constraint(equalToConstant: statusBarHeight).isActive = true
        statusbarView.widthAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        statusbarView.topAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        statusbarView.centerXAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        let appearanceNav = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearanceNav.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 125.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 159.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        appearanceNav.largeTitleTextAttributes.updateValue(UIColor.white, forKey: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor)
        appearanceNav.titleTextAttributes.updateValue(UIColor.white, forKey: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor)
        appearanceNav.shadowColor = nil
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearanceNav
        navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearanceNav
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearanceNav
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Thank you!

Comment: Put in a VStack {}.background(.YourColor)

Comment: You haven't included enough code to demonstrate the problem. Please include a [mre]

Comment: You're right, I'll add the code for the ContentView in the question...

Comment: You may want to replace HomeView(), CategoryView(), and GalleryView() in your demo code with simple Text views, while you wait for the best answer.  Otherwise people might start asking for those views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heightAnchor, topAnchor, and centerXAnchor may be in conflict with each other.  Just use widthAnchor, topAnchor, and bottomAnchor.

```
statusbarView.widthAnchor
    .constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
statusbarView.topAnchor
    .constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
statusbarView.bottomAnchor
    .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: That's it, with this tweak now it's working correctly...
I also find why the other code you suggested didn't work...I tried with a new Xcode project, with iOS 16.4 as minimum deployment, and your first code works fine, but the problem is that my app has iOS 14 as minimum deployment, and that in some way breaks the layout...

Comment: You are right.  I tried it in iOS 15 and 16, and it worked, but not iOS 14.  I'll note that above.

Comment: Perfect... I think the problem is solved, unfortunately I can accept only one answer so I accept the one that worked best for my specific situation, but both answers are really really good...thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This only works for iOS 15 and above (I'm currently using iOS 16)

I found that offsetting a view below the top of the safe area causes its background color to extend to the top of the screen.  Then you don't have to wrap your tab view items in navigation views, and can get rid of the UINavigationController extension.  See the last two lines in my version of your code, below.

I'm not exactly sure why this works.  Potentially, it's exploiting a bug in SwiftUI, and the behavior could change in the future.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selected = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            Text("Home View")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 0 ? "house.fill" : "house"))
                    Text("Home")
                }.tag(0)
            
            Text("Category View")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 1 ? "text.justify" : "text.justify"))
                    Text("Categorie")
                }.tag(1)
            
            Text("Gallery View")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 2 ? "photo.fill" : "photo"))
                    Text("Galleria")
                }.tag(2)
            
            SearchView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 3 ? "magnifyingglass" : "magnifyingglass"))
                    Text("Ricerca")
                }.tag(3)
        }
        .accentColor(.white)
        .onAppear() {
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 125.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 159.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 125.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 159.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        .offset(CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)) // move TabView down one point
        .background(Color(red: 125.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 159.0/255.0))
    }
}
```

[image: TabView with colored unsafe area]

Comment: I tried to replace my code with your code and removed the extension, but unfortunately it doesn't work...now the status bar is white again...