# How to remove the gap between status bar and page in .NET MAUI on iPhone 15

Tags: ios, maui

I'm developing an application using .NET MAUI and I've noticed a significant gap between the status bar and the page on iPhone 15 Pro Max. However, when I run the same application on iPhone 13 Pro Max, there's no such gap. I've checked solutions shared on Stack Overflow for a similar issue [White line between status bar and WebView on iPhone 14 Pro/Pro Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76015211/white-line-between-status-bar-and-webview-on-iphone-14-pro-pro-max), but I couldn't find a solution specific to .NET MAUI framework. Do you have any suggestions on how to close this gap? Where can I find the necessary settings or platform customizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to remove the gap between status bar and page in .NET MAUI on iPhone 15

About this, you can refer to this issue on MAUI GitHub: [Extra space below status bar on iPhone 14 Pro Max #16617](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16617#issuecomment-1670675788).

And yes, it uses Handler/PlatformView (*Where can I find the necessary settings or platform customizations?*).